# Launchd Plist file not running after reboot

Tags: objective-c, macos, authentication, plist, launchd

I am creating an OSX app the requires GUI at the login page of a iMac and I was wondering (if possible) I could run a launchd plist file after reboot. The following plist file is in the **"/Library/LaunchAgents/"** directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
         <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
       <string>com.example.apple-samplecode.PreLoginAgentCocoa</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
       <string>LoginWindow</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
       <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/PreLoginAgentCocoa.app/Contents/MacOS/PreLoginAgentCocoa</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The file works for when I log out from the desktop but doesn't work when I restart the computer.

Any help is useful.

Answer (score 1):

> an OSX app the requires GUI at the login page of a iMac

`LaunchAgents` are executed for the currently logged in session user. When you reboot the Mac and are presented with the login screen, there is no session user.

As [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ) states: -

> A user agent is essentially identical to a daemon, but is specific to a given logged-in user and executes only while that user is logged in

Without the given 'logged-in user', your application cannot be executed as a `LaunchAgent`.

> The file works for when I log out from the desktop

The session user is still available at this time, so will function on logout, before the session user is released.

Comment: Could I make a LaunchDeamon as well and then it would show at the login screen.

Comment: Would I add the script to the Launch Deamon is there anything I would change?

Comment: I figured it out, I have an encrypted drive so my mac logins in and then boots causing the loginwindow screen not to show but if your mac is not encrypted it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between putting `plist` file into below directories

`/Library/LaunchAgents` : It will run as agent. Agents run within user sessions, as the logged-in user.

`/Library/LaunchDaemons` : It will run as a daemon. Daemons run in system context independent of who is logged in and usually run as a root.

If you want to start your service/script at the reboot of the machine then you need to put your `plist` file into the `/Library/LaunchDaemons` folder and execute the following commands.

```
sudo launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/${YOUR_SERVICE_NAME}.plist
sudo launchctl enable system/${YOUR_SERVICE_NAME}
sudo launchctl kickstart -kp system/${YOUR_SERVICE_NAME}
```

Note: It will launch service with user root and start system-wide.

References:
Launchctl Man Page(https://ss64.com/osx/launchctl.html)

Comment: What are the commands to remove and uninstall this service?

Comment: @Vikaschhabra have written a detailed gist for this https://gist.github.com/shubhwip/d47b685ce1e5f67f6367d49a5aa578b0

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @shubham's answer, the *minimum* required ownership/file permissions for the .plist file to **run at user-login** (under Monterrey, at least) are:

- location: `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

  - ownership: the user owning the folder (or root)
  - readable: by the user
  - writable:
  - executable:

In my own case, I got it executing automatically, following reboot (+login) with:

```bash
-r--------    1 foobar  wheel   1.6K Nov  4 14:26 myScript.plist
```